# Report XML of screenos-config

Tags: screenos

tell me please, who Knows is there xml output of config in screenos.  In Junos it achieve by command-- show | display xml .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no XML output for Juniper ScreenOS devices. Only Junos devices have XML configuration output as the underlying management system on those devices uses XML.

Comment: you confirmed my assumptions